# How to prevent css from breaking words if only 1-2 characters would be moved?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I prevent css from breaking words if only 1-2 letter would be moved? Is there a way to break word only for 3 letters or more?

Yes, I know word-break,

I also tried wrapping words in `<span>` with `inline-block` attributes like this

`<span>Buchstaben</span><span>entsprechungen</span>`

to enforce different breaking but in some cases it doesn't help and I search for another way of breaking words.

[image: single letters]

Thanks

Comment: Use white-space nowrap like the below
<span style="white-space: nowrap">no-breaks-here</span>

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS...it can't *count* characters. You need JS.

Comment: Just give your columns appropriate sizes and/or insert manual breaks in titles with `<br/>`